# Java websocket onError executes with infinite loop

Tags: java, websocket, endpoint, onerror

I am having problem with infinity loop. when I got the error, onError method(Endpoint.class) is executed infinitely. I tried to fix it, It failed.

So, I have something which I am curious about WebSocket API to fix it.

1. After onError method (when onError method finished), What execute? 
   probably, after onError method finished, something execute and it makes another other error.

endpoint code is here.

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
    server.register(session);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) {
    server.handle(message, session);
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(String sessionId) {
    server.unregister(sessionId);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Session session, Throwable exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();        
}
```

flow is here

1. Error occur in somewhere
2. onError method is executed.
3. after onError(just printing stacktrace), also Error method execute again.

<3.> is executed infinitely.

I want to know this. thank you.!

Comment: I am curious about onething more.
using onError method, can I make server being run?

Comment: Usually, when server got Error, It will die..